# Clustering Docker containers behind load-balancers for HA

Tags: java, docker, cluster-computing, load-balancing, high-availability

Most Docker literature boasts that you can run hundreds, even thousands of containers on the same physical server. I'm wondering what this looks like from a load-balancing/clustering perspective.

Say I have a RESTful web service, `fizz-service.war`. Typically, with "normal" VMs, I might deploy this service to 50 VMs (say, `fizzsvc01.example.com` through `fizzsvc50.example.com`) and then cluster/load balance those VMs behind a service URL, such as `http://fizz-service.example.com`. When a request comes in, the load balancer select a node to forward the request on to, say, `fizzsvc34:8080/fizz-service`.

**I'm wondering how this works with Docker containers.** If I have the same 50 containers running across, say, 5 nodes:

- Can those nodes be either VMs or physical servers?
- For the containers running on the same nodes, do they each run on their own port? Otherwise, how could you have 50 instances of the service running on the same port?
- Whereas with "normal VMs", the load balancer is configured with all the VMs that make up the pool, and then I just deploy my service to each VM in the pool, how does this change with Docker containers? How does my load balancer (likely a separate piece of infrastructure such as F5 or nginx) "*know*" about all the containers available to distribute load to?

Or does my whole approach to HA/load balancing need to change when I step into Docker-land?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each container will be running on a dedicated port (normally allocated by Docker) and you'll need some mechanism to keep track of each container, in order to generate the configuration for your load balancer.

So nothing really changes, except the number of containers is potentially much larger, requiring automation in order to be practical. Containers are much more instant compared to virtual machines.

Comment: Thanks @Mark O'Connor (+1 and green check) - can I assume then that containers are perfect candidates for service discovery tools like ZooKeeper/Consul/Eureka?

Comment: @smeeb Absolutely and checkout a nifty tool called registrator that can help with consul: http://jlordiales.me/2015/02/03/registrator/